# Values of read SPI data in a loop change if printing the value

Tags: python, pi-3, arduino, spi

I'm trying to read in values from an Arduino. It's sending the data properly (checked with another Arduino), but the Pi doesn't seem to be getting it properly. I've created a function to read in a number of values from the Arduino since `spi.readbytes(n)` doesn't appear to be working at all.

```
def read_bytes(n):
    b = []
    for i in range(n):
        v = spi.xfer2([0x00])[0]
        b.append(v)
    return b

print(read_bytes(15 * 3))
```

This returns some of the correct values, but not in the correct positions. If I change the code to print anything inside of the loop, the correct values are returned. Of course, I don't want to print something in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking a good deal about my problem, I realized that printing slows down the code execution a non-negligible amount. I changed `spi.max_speed_hz` to a lower value to align better with the Arduino's capabilities and it all works fine now.